# Format Decimal 2 Places - no trailing zeroes

Tags: c#, string-formatting

The format: #,# formats my number but it rounds my decimals up. I need to keep my decimals. Is there a format for that?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you *never* want to round up, so 1.9999m should show as 1.9? Sample input and desired output would be useful...

Comment: How many decimals you need? do you have allways the same amount? , is the decimal separator? string format types on google didn't help you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`#,#.###`

Ad as many `#`s as needed.
To *always* show decimal places, use `0`s instead.

Comment: Thanks - I had thought this was it, but it's not working well with  my Infragistics UltraGrid. I'll have to go about this a different way. Thank you.

Comment: This was a mistake on my part - my column that I was trying to format was being returned as Int32 - apparently the  UltraGrid didn't like that. Thanks.

Comment: String.Format("{0:#,0.00}", value) did my job.

Comment: @HasanGürsoy: `value.ToString("#,0.00")`.  Don't use `String.Format` unless you're building a composite format string.

Comment: So how can I use this formatting for a decimal? I want to see it like 0,00 or 1.111,11?

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate decimal places with

```
(int)d
```

If you need two decimals you can write

```
(int)(100*d)/100.0
```

---

```
(int)(100*1.99999)/100.0 ==> 1.99
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to display it as a string, try this...

```
yourVariable.ToString("{0:F2}");
```

This will format the string into a fixed point with two floating numbers.

The [Microsoft Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) and [Microsoft Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) pages have useful data you could refer to. :-)

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin.Forms you can format your data bindings like this:

```
<Label
 x:Name="label_expenseAmount"
 Text="{Binding Expense, StringFormat='{0:F2}'}"
 />
```

This will format your decimal properties nicely to your UI.  Put your label in a data template of a collection view and you can display a full list of expenses this way without any C# formatting whatsoever.

[image: Image of labels formatted using XAML string formatting.]